# wp plugin not working after website live

Tags: plugins

Im trying to understand Wordpress plugins, i made a nice little plugin that lets you upload an image to media.

However, this only works on localhost, after i moved the files to my host it stopped working.

The button of my plugin still works, when i click it it redirects me to an empty page.

How should i resolve this issue?

Heres my index: https://pastebin.com/CU7AeGWD
Heres the button: https://pastebin.com/bLG50tJp

Tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to this site and plugin development in general! "stopped working" isn't really telling much, have you tried [debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) this further?

Comment: thank you, yes ive done something and now the only error im getting has to do with this: function _custom_menu_page(), so i think i didnt link it correctly , i might be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following

- You have checked the URL of your Wordpress installation
- You have checked that your webhosting is compatible with uploading (file permissions, user rights)
- You re-saved the permalinks (to make sure that URLs are used correctly)

Edit: This little amount of information gives us little space to work with. Also, please check that you have WP Debug set to true as it might provide you with information that you would normally not get.

Comment: I got this after setting it to true:
https://pastebin.com/wNgfwrx9

Comment: Is this a plugin that you're using to upload with? If not, try disabling to check if it might change the functionality of your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to include WordPress files from `wp-admin` folder because you are using `media_handle_upload` in admin side. They are necessary only when you want to upload from front-end.

So you can remove these lines of codes:

```
$path = get_home_path();

require_once( $path . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( $path . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( $path . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
```

Then, please try to fill the `action` attribute of your `form` using `#` because the empty value is not valid and it could make issues while submitting form.

Also non of your debug log is related to your codes.

Check [`media_handle_upload` documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) for sample codes.

Edit: In order to debug your code and see what is result of upload, you can use `error_log` function after activating `WP_DEBUG_LOG`.

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'fileToUpload', 0);
// Log results.
ob_start();
var_dump( $attachment_id );
error_log( ob_get_clean() );
```

Then you can check `wp-content/debug.log` file to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, so if none of my debug log is related to my code, could it be the host blocking the file uploader?

Comment: I think not. You can try upload a simple image in media and see if it works or not. Did you tried changing action from empty value to `#`?

Comment: I uploaded an image to media , so that worked and yes i changed the action to '#'

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for helping me and making my code better!
This is the solution:
function _custom_menu_page(){
    include_once **DIR** . '/index.php';
}
It finally works!